# Build dynamic targets for different architectures using make?

Tags: go, makefile, build, compilation, gnu-make

I'm looking for a way to basically iterate over a list of architectures and build unique ones using make.  For example, I have a variable containing all the architectures, and a static target currently.

Below is the (simplified) logic I have.

```
ALL_ARCHES=amd64 arm arm64  
VERSION=$(shell git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)-$(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)

cmd/mything/mything: cmd/mything/*.go
            CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-X main.version=$(VERSION)" -o $@ cmd/mything/*.go
...
```

I basically want to replace `GOARCH=amd64` by iterating over the `ALL_ARCHES` variable, creating a unique binary that represents the given architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you accept to name your binaries `cmd/mything/mything-ARCH`, where `ARCH` is the target architecture, you could try:

```
ALL_ARCHES := amd64 arm arm64   
VERSION    := $(shell git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)-$(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)

.PHONY: all

all: $(addprefix cmd/mything/mything-,$(ALL_ARCHES))

cmd/mything/mything-%: cmd/mything/*.go
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=$* go build -ldflags "-X main.version=$(VERSION)" -o $@ $^
```

`$*` is the automatic variable that expands as the stem of the target name in a pattern rule.

Comment: It looks like that should work, when I run it though I get `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`, not really sure why?

Comment: After banging my head against the wall I discovered my variable was wrong. 
 `ALL_ARCHES` should be `amd64 arm arm64` instead of `$(amd64 arm arm64)`

Comment: Right. I should have noticed this instead of blindly copy-pasting. Fixed in my answer. By the way, I also changed the recursively expanded variables to simply expanded variables. In your case it is probably preferable (at least for `ALL_ARCHES`). And I used the `$^` automatic variable instead of repeating `cmd/mything/*.go` in the recipe.

Comment: Thanks!  What is the difference between recursive expansion and simple expansion?

Comment: There is no better explanation about the two flavours of variables than the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors).